# How can I map my entity to a table in .Net Core project without using Entity Framework and only using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, ado.net

I have a project for Entities and I am using ADO.NET code for normal CRUD operations on this entity. I would like to map my entity name to table names, Could you please provide me a way to do it. With .Net Standard I could use System.Data.Linq.Mapping. But my project is in .Net Core 2.2 and I cannot add these as a reference, tried changing target framework, but my other projects are not compatible. Kindly advise me how do I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of options.

1) Create a Mapper class that accepts T1 & T2.. And do the mapping manually for each property.

2) Use a library such as Automapper that does all this for you automatically (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: The automapper and mapper class would have worked if my T1 and T2 were both Objects in C#. I am trying to map C# object to a SQL object residing in a Database. How will I achieve this - as again using that C# object I create queries which should translate to the correct DB table name and execute in DB using ado.net

Comment: I think the “full” answer to this may be way beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.. Is there a reason you cant use an ORM like EF? Because mapping C# objects to SQL and producing the SQL from LINQ statements to drive it, is quite a hefty piece of work.. Thats why EF exists.